# How to testfor a player that entered an area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In a Minecraft server I was trying to make a soccer goal, and I wanted it to detect when a player is exactly in that region (the goal). How to detect if a player is in a exact region?

Answer (score 1):

To testfor a player in some distance from a certain point use

```
/testfor @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R,rm=RM]
```

Explanation:

```
/testfor                             % test for
         @a[                     ]   % all players...
                        r=R,rm=RM    % from RM to R blocks away from
            x=X,y=Y,z=Z,             % the coordinates [X, Y, Z]
```

To run a command when somebody enters the area, use

```
/execute @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R,rm=RM] ~ ~ ~ /say Somebody is in between RM and R blocks away from [X,Y,Z]!
```

(put any command you need after the `~`'s)

If you want to detect players in a square rather then circular area, use

```
/testfor @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,dx=DX,dy=DY,dz=DZ]
```

Explanation:

```
/testfor                                     % test for
         @a[                             ]   % all players...
            x=X,        dx=DX,               % with x coordinates from X to X+DX,
                y=Y,          dy=DY,         % with y coordinates from Y to Y+DY,
                    z=Z,            dz=DZ    % with z coordinates from Z to Z+DZ
```

The command can be "placed" into a `/execute` command similarly like above.

Comment: @DumboFlumbo If this answer solved your problem, then feel free to click that checkmark to the left of the answer! That will let others know that your problem was solved, which makes it easier for future visitors with the same problem to find a solution. Thanks!